# Weblogic 10 JDBC Data Source Descriptions

Tags: configuration, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, portal

**Introduction**

When creating a new domain for Weblogic Portal 10.3.0.0, the following datasources are created by default for use by the Weblogic Server (including the Name and JNDI Names).

For Example:

I am sure the `p13nDataSource` is accessed by the `SQLAuthenticator` Authentication Provider for performing DBMS authentication.

```
NAME                        JNDI NAME 

cgDataSource                cgDataSource
cgDataSource-nonXA          cgDataSource-nonXA
p13nDataSource              p13n.trackingDataSource p13n.sequencerDataSource cm.sequencerDataSource p13n.leasemanager p13n.dataSyncDataSource p13n.entitlementsDataSource p13n.quiescenceDataSource p13n.credentialsDataSource
portalDataSource            weblogic.jdbc.jts.commercePool contentDataSource contentVersioningDataSource portalFrameworkPool
portalDataSourceAlwaysXA    portalDataSourceAlwaysXA
portalDataSourceNeverXA     portalFrameworkPoolNeverXA
```

**Question**

I understand the difference between `XA` and `Non-XA`, but does anyone have any information or descriptions regarding what each of the other data sources are used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Default JDBC Configuration for the Basic WebLogic Platform Domain](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/docs81/db_mgmt/default_JDBC_configs.html) docs on Oracle documentation provides you some insight. Unfortunately, these docs are for version 8.1 (I haven't found the 10.3 version of it), but a lot of them remain true for 10.3.